# How to show json external api in input field in Angular 9?

Tags: angular

I have this external api for testing:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

And I would like to show the results in an autocomplete input field of Angular 9. I got my autocomplete like in the example:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

But, instead of the name of the states, I need to show the json output in an input field. How can I achieve that? I am new in Angular. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can stringfy the json and show it in the option field. But on what bases you gonna search ??

Comment: hi, i dont understand what you mean :(